# How to combat muscular atrophy while in coma?

Tags: injections, coma-comatose, muscular-atrophy, muscular-dystrophy

Muscles start to deteriorate without use, so without the person consciously moving a body part or flexing, can muscle tissue degeneration be stopped or at least decelerated by administering something, some passive technique, or machine assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you could combat muscular degeneration.

What you could do is

- Massage
- (Higher protein intake by infusion)
- (Electrical muscle stimulation ([EMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_muscle_stimulation))
- (Steroids)

But it's an intervention that's not essential for life and probably dangerous so this isn't practical.

Comment: would massages be able to be automated?

Comment: Reliable references?

Comment: This post has the makings of a very good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)